# DirectoryIterator order changed in different environments? PHP

Tags: php, unix

I purposefully named files as numbers in a directory;

DIR [
  0.php,
  1.php,
  2.php,
  3.php
]

so that I could iterate throgh them in order. On my localhost DirectoryIterator works fine and in order. However when on an ubuntu server, the order goes from

from
0 - 1 - 2 - 3 
to 
0 - 1 - 3 - 2

Anyone ever run into this or have any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: Can't say I experienced it or know why it's happening. But I assume you're loading the file names into an array. So why not simply use [asort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) on it?

Comment: Wow thanks! That was a great solution lol